# Getting error cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'settings'

Tags: java, xml

I am facing error `cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'settings'` in `settings.xml`

Below is my code snippet of settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
```

How can I resolve this error?